# Any way make object initialization short and clean?

Tags: c#, initialization

I have similar code like

```
public static LongWrittingType types = new LongWrittingType();
```

It is long. The type `LongWrittingType` is repeated. Any short writing for this?

Comment: What is long? The name of the class you created?

Comment: You could switch to a terse programming langauge

Comment: For `static` variables.. not that I know about, but it will be a nice enhancement

Comment: Nope, there's no equivalent to `var` to member/static variables. But to be fair, is this such a big deal? Auto-complete must be doing a lot of the heavy lifting for you...

Comment: its too much obsession. why do you even care ? and in my point of view  its not long at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about the class name being long you can use a declaration to shorten it.

```
using Short = Sandbox.ReallyLongClassNameBecauseICan;
```

Then inside that file you can use it like the example below.

```
Short types = new Short();
```

Basically this assigned an alias to the class name.

Comment: I would recommend not using `Short` for this.  Even though it's not an issue in C#, `Short` is a keyword in VB and this might cause confusion if the code is ever translated.

Comment: Yes, `short` is also a keyword in C# so it can get confusing. This is just an example.